# "multiple" FormatAreaStyles.css files possible?

Tags: 2011, rtf

for our current project, we have to use/extend the FormatAreaStyles.css to give content editors a good impression in the RTF editor on how the text will look like on the page.

I've done this before in other project, but for this implementation we have different website styles/types hosted in the same CMS instance (in fact 'old' styling and the 'new' design). The client doesn't want to show the new default font, colors etc. on the old RTF fields and visa-verse.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this in T2011 SP1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The only option you have to my knowledge is to use different classes for the old and new design. But for generics like a font specification on the body there really isn't a solution, unless you think in terms of a UI extension that determines this based on the Schema (provided you have different Schemas for the old and new design).

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem either. Just make sure that the body elements of different page types have a class identifying the page type. In fact, that's probably the only change you need in your html.

Comment: I think don't the OP is worried about his styling in a Page, it's about the styling as seen in an RTF in the CMS where he wants to differentiate between the old and new design, there is no Page object or option for different body classes per Page Type available there.

Comment: Since the available classes only show when the correct (nested) node is selected, this approach could even restrict which classes are available to authors.  You could adjust each field's top-level node (via each RTF's XSLT filter). However, in the case of shared content, it might be better to make CME Preview the more realistic view (easier on authors and developers in the long run across multiple sites).

Comment: yes as long as the Schemas for the old and new design are different, you can have different classes available in the RTF, but when the font style is set on the body, there is no way to differentiate without building a UI extension.

Comment: Doh! You are right. There isn't really a 'body', but maybe the solution isn't so far away. What we need is the ability to configure "page context" css for RTFs. A GUI extension would be good to demo this, but I see it more as an ER.